# I am getting strange output when using map() on array of objects, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, es5-compatiblity

I am filtering null values from an array of objects but receiving not a clean array as output

```js
//returns ,cat,snake,dog,cat,snake
//var input1 = [{"dog":"35","cat":"21","girrafe":"33","snake":"44"},{"dog":"22","cat":"","girrafe":"2","snake":""},{"dog":"","cat":"","girrafe":"88","snake":""}];

//returns ",,dog,girrafe,snake"
//var input1 = [{"dog":"43","cat":"32","girrafe":"1","snake":"33"},{"dog":"1","cat":"23","girrafe":"1","snake":"23"},{"dog":"","cat":"5","girrafe":"","snake":""}];

//returns dog,,dog,cat,snake
//var input1 = [{"dog":"","cat":"s","girrafe":"1","snake":"54"},{"dog":"x","cat":"y","girrafe":"45","snake":"x"},{"dog":"","cat":"","girrafe":"1","snake":""}];

//tried to fix with .join() but then

//returns doggirrafecat,girrafe if I uses console.log(input1.join())
var input1 = [{"dog":"","cat":"s","girrafe":"1","snake":"54"},{"dog":"x","cat":"y","girrafe":"","snake":"x"},{"dog":"s","cat":"","girrafe":"","snake":"ss"}];


//returns typeof object
var emptyKeys = input1.map(function (object) {
    return Object.keys(object).filter(function (key) {
        return object[key] === '';
    });
});

console.log(emptyKeys)
```

So my goal is to get empty values in array of objects and get their keys. What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix it so that all inputs are return correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you looking to get all empty `strings` in the array?

Comment: yes get empty values in array of objects and get their keys

Comment: @JohnLong what is your expected output? It seems to be fine as your map will return an empty array for an object who does not have any keys with empty value.

Comment: The format of the the result that is being returned is a problem, I want object like "dog,cat,snake,dog" but I get sometimes weird commas for different inputs.

Comment: Are you turning your result to a string? Because that's how you'd get extra commas. You have an array *of arrays* and when you turn it into a string each array inside will also be turned into a string. You need to flatten the top array.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, as a string all I want to return from these inputs is one array in the best scenario but string is fine too.

Comment: Then [flatten your array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) and turn it into a string.

Comment: `flattenArrEmptykeys = emptyKeys.flat(2);`

Comment: awesome. thanks!! I used var flatArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], input1); because I am on ES5

Comment: If you need to turn into a `string`, you can use this instead: `flattenArrEmptykeys = emptyKeys.flat(2).toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Flattening the array solved it,

```js
var flatArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], input1);
```

Thanks for the suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var emptyKeys = input1.map(function (object) {
    return Object.keys(object).filter(function (key) {
        return object[key] === '';
    });
}).filter(function(item){
 return item.length !== 0;
});
```

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
input1.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){
    accumulator.push(...Object.entries(currentValue).filter((kvPair) => kvPair[1] === '').map(ele => ele[0]));
    return accumulator;
}, [])
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would solve the OPs problem?